# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, yfinance

In `yfinance` I'm trying to get historical stock data of certain elements from `.info` and It returned the error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'`. I'm quite new to python, so can anyone tell me why this happens? and how to solve it? thank you

```
import yfinance as yf

ticker = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
ticker2 = ticker.info
data = ticker2["priceToBook"]
df = yf.download(data, start="2020-1-1", end="2021-1-1")
print(df)
```

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\test\temp.py", line 6, in <module>
    df = yf.download(data, start="2020-1-1", end="2021-1-1", replace=False)
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 73, in download
    tickers, (list, set, tuple)) else tickers.replace(',', ' ').split()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Please give the full traceback.

Comment: what is the contents of `data`? I guess it must be string, but I'm not sure `ticker2["priceToBook"]` gives a string value.

Comment: I have edited it, the traceback is there

Comment: @AliTou , I used `print(type(data))` it returned `<class 'float'>`

Comment: @Mirkyly That's the problem. I'm not much familiar with `yfinance` and what you're trying to achieve, but examples in the Internet use something like `yf.download("AMZN AAPL GOOG", #other args` which means you have to pass a string as the first argument.

Comment: @AliTou Well yes, those examples are different from what I want to achieve with this code, is there a way that my variable `data` can be converted to a string too?

Comment: Simply you can use `str(data)` but I'm not sure it'll give you the desired output.

Comment: The value you get for 'priceToBook' is a float. It is not a symbol name.

Comment: @r-beginners yes, but I'd like to clarify that I want to get historical data of `priceToBook`, do you know how?

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think you can get it on yfinance. Is the data you want to know about available [here](https://ycharts.com/companies/MSFT/price_to_book_value)? You may be able to get it by scraping.

Comment: @r-beginners yes, that's exactly right, but scraping is relatively more difficult than using `yfinance` so that's why I tried using `yfinance` but anyways thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: If you become a member of ycharts, you will be able to get data via API. That's what I thought when I saw [this](https://github.com/ycharts/pycharts).